# Try Catch when looping in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, try-catch

I am trying to incorporate a `tryCatch` function in my R code to prevent the loop from breaking whenever I get an error.

I've looked through other examples but can't make applying `tryCatch` work.

Does anyone know how to add `tryCatch` to the following loop to prevent any error stopping the loop continuing?

```
for (i in (1:nrow(pagedata))) {
    u <- pagedata[i, "id"]
    url <- paste0("https://www.google.com/", u)
    r <- GET(url)
    print(url)
    if (!http_error(r)) {
        web_page_read_follows <- read.csv(url)
        colnames(web_page_read_follows) <- "follows"
        web_page_collect_follows <- web_page_read_follows[web_page_read_follows$follows %like% "Followers", ]
        web_page_collect_follows <- as.data.frame(web_page_collect_follows)
        colnames(web_page_collect_follows) <- "follows"
        web_page_collect_follows$follows <- gsub("Followers.*", "", web_page_collect_follows$follows)
        web_page_collect_follows$follows <- gsub(".*=", "", web_page_collect_follows$follows)
        web_page_collect_follows <- tail(web_page_collect_follows, -(nrow(web_page_collect_follows) - 1))
        if (length(web_page_collect_follows$follows) > 0) {
            pagedata[i, "followers"] <- web_page_collect_follows$follows
            print(i)
            Sys.sleep(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the function in the loop generating the error? It's there that you will use `tryCatch`. Can you post a sample of `pagedata`? Maybe `dput(head(pagedata, 20))`.

Comment: You've solved it for me thanks!
The issue was around the read.csv function, which I've put the tryCatch around now :)